# Gather all textboxes on a form, generate GUIDs for each of them

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have 10 textboxes on a webform and I would like to use C# to assign separate guids to each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control MyControl in Form1.Controls)
    {
        TextBox MyTextBox = MyControl as TextBox;

        if (MyTextBox != null)
        {
            MyTextBox.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have

```
static class ControlExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(this Control parent)
        {
            foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
            {
                yield return control;
                foreach (Control descendant in control.GetAllControls())
                {
                    yield return descendant;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and call

```
this.GetAllControls().OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(t => t.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```